# Can a unitary with size not a power of 2 be used for Quantum Phase Estimation?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms

For Quantum Phase Estimation, we need a Unitary Matrix $ U $ such that

$$
U~|\psi\rangle = e^{2 \pi i \theta}~|\psi\rangle
$$

Using QPE, we can find the phase $\theta$.

My question is about the size of the Unitary $U$. What if the size of the matrix $U$ is not a power of 2? Will QPE still work??

Answer (score 3):

Much of the magic of the discrete Fourier transform, be it classical or quantum, lies in the fact that a large $N\times N$ matrix can be factored into a tensor product of $\mathcal{O}(\log N)$ smaller matrices.  This much was worked out by [Cooley and Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) back in the 60's, with antecedents even earlier going back to Gauss.

Perhaps it's best to think of the QFT as a tensor product of $n$ single-qubit ($d=2$) gates - thus the size of the matrix is $2^n\times 2^n$.  **The radix of $2$ is convenient and not required.** For example one can also think of a tensor product of $n$ qutrit ($d=3$) gates, in which case the matrix is $3^n\times 3^n$, or any other qudit gates.  Indeed, Shor's original algorithm for discrete logarithms envisioned a mixed-radix Fourier transform; Coppersmith quickly improved Shor's Fourier transform to the familiar form we see today.

But perhaps you're asking whether the input vector itself, $|\psi\rangle$, needs to be a power of two.  Thinking about the (classical) Fast Fourier Transform of a dataset that is not a power of two, this is addressed with "zero-padding" the input data set to the next nearest power of two.  This [link](https://www.bitweenie.com/listings/fft-zero-padding/) may be helpful.  Thus you can always zero-pad your vector $|\psi\rangle$ to be a power of two.  But, the computational costs associated with this padding may not be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In more general terms, quantum phase estimation will be the task of estimating the action of *any* unitary $U = e^{-iA\theta}$ for a parameter $\theta$ that we want to know and any Hermitian operator $A$.

There is no restriction on the form/size of the unitary besides encoding the parameter $\theta$ in the evolution according to the Stones Theorem. Quantum Parameter Estimation will work; different protocols will be less/more efficient and use different nonclassical resources for such.

**Remark:** Other assumptions may be relevant for non-triviality, given protocol, etc., for instance it is also relevant that "$A$ is not totally degenerate, in case all eigenvalues of $A$ are identical the unitary would not imprint the parameter onto the state in a relative phase." [A bit before Eq. 4](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17559-w).

Comment: Theoretically, it might be possible to use any Unitary but is it actually possible to implement a Unitary with a size not a power of 2 on a quantum computer?